# Keyboard shortcut to an action in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

How to define a keyboard shortcut (accelerator) to an action associated with a context menu item of `TreeViewer` or `TableViewer` (or any control in general).

I have trees and tables of different kind of objects and I have generic actions like "move up", "move down", "expand" or "collapse". I created context menus for table or tree controls, but I want the user to be able to call actions without necessity of right clicking on selection (or without necessity of using mouse in general). For example "Move up" action should be called when the viewer is focused and user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>.
Setting accelerator to that actions does not work. I do not also want to add the actions to main menu bar (like Edit menu etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you are using `Action` for your actions.

Call

```
setActionDefinitionId("command id");
```

in your Action constructor to specify a command that this action handles.

Declare the command in your plugin.xml using the `org.eclipse.ui.commands` extension point.

Use the `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point to bind a key sequence to the command.

Comment: Can't it be done without affecting the plugin.xml? Also I can't find the org.eclipse.ui.keys extendsion point. There is keyBinding item in the org.eclipse.ui.commands. Can it be used instead?

Comment: Sorry should have been `org.eclipse.ui.bindings` extension point. You can always handle `KeyDown` events on the table and check for your shortcut keys

Answer (score 1):

Just for future generations:

I followed Greg's advice and added KeyListsner to the viewer control. This is a snippet of my class that wraps StructuredViewer:

```
private class ViewerWrapper{

    private StructuredViewer fViewer;

    [...]

    private class ViewerKeyAdapter implements KeyAdapter{
        private int fKeyCode;
        private Action fAction;
        private int fStateMask;

        public ViewerKeyAdapter(int keyCode, int stateMask, Action action){
            fKeyCode = keyCode;
            fStateMask = stateMask;
            fAction = action;
        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            if((e.stateMask & fStateMask) != 0 || fStateMask == SWT.NONE){
                if(e.keyCode == fKeyCode){
                    fAction.run();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    [...]

    public void addKeyListener(int keyCode, int stateMask, Action action){
        fViewer.getControl().addKeyListener(new ViewerKeyAdapter(keyCode, modifier, action));
    }
}
```

Most of the time I spent on this was to realize that `SWT.UP` and `SWT.ARROW_UP` is not the same...